# filtering large wiggles in signals

Tags: fft, fourier-transform, ifft, time-frequency, signal-synthesis

I am trying to filter out large wiggles showing in a signal. Those wiggles are happening due to many signal processing layers and a final sine Fourier transform (no phase)

Here's the python code i am using to compute the sine Fourier tranform

```
def sine_f_transform(x, signal, nx):
    # x: the x axis vector in real dimension
    # signal: the y axis vector that we need fourier transfored
    # nx: the x axis vector in the reciprocal space
    nsignal = np.zeros(len(x), dtype=float)
    xsignal = x*signal
    dx      = x[1]-x[0]
    for ridx, r in enumerate(nx):
        sinxr = dx * np.sin(x*r)
        nsignal[ridx] = (2./np.pi) * np.sum( xsignal * sinxr )
    return nsignal
```

Signal vector is the result of multiple transformation. It's pointless to try to explain the meaning of it here. The main point here, i need to to filter out the large wiggles in 'transformed signal' as those are not needed and it's giving me a headache to find a general solution for that.

below you can see what the signal looks like and the sine Fourier transformed one looks like. The large wiggles that i'm desperately trying to remove are the ones in 'transformed signal'

I tried all the following:

- fft 'transformed signal' zeroing out frequencies and then ifft
- convoluting 'signal' with sinc prior to doing the sine_f_transform
- appying scipy.signal.filtfilt on Butterworth filters ...

Any help would be appreciated

thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: **It's pointless to try to explain ...** you are trying find help with repairing a signal but you don't want to explain what the damage is and where it comes from. I'm afraid there is no "magic" solution here without going into the gory derails of how the damage was done.

Comment: 'signal' is a slice of an observed quantity of particle matter interaction. original observation can reach up to 20 or 30. Now in this particular case i am applying a cutoff at around ~0.8 and then applying a sine fourier transform on that and obtaining 'transformed signal'  The large wiggles that we see is an artifact due to the limited size of the vector signal. The periodicity of those wiggles are nothing else but 2*pi*(signal_x[-1]-signal_x[0]) I can always compute multiple 'transformed signal'  with different 'signal' cutoffs and average all of those to cancel out the wiggles. not ideal!